# C#, Sentry и unhandled exception: как они это делают?

Tags: c#, .net-core, try-catch

Уважаемые господа,

я начал пробовать использовать централизованный логгинг - через сайт [sentry.io](https://sentry.io/).

Практически там просто выбираешь тип проекта, пишешь его название, и система говорит "о, вот этот кусок кода вставь туда то, и будет тебе счастье!"

В моём случае, я экспериментировал с C# и WinForms, сайт предложил мне переписать обычный запуск проекта с

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

на

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        SentrySdk.Init(o =>
        {
            // Tells which project in Sentry to send events to:
            o.Dsn = "https://c6bc440221b040a018edf172dc02167@o1300122.ingest.sentry.io/63136";
            // When configuring for the first time, to see what the SDK is doing:
            o.Debug = true;
            // Set TracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for performance monitoring.
            // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
            o.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;
        });

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Потом я поигрался  с тем, что в Sentry можно "написать" посредством вызова

`SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Hello Sentry");`

и подумал, что во все `try-catch` нало будет добавлять теперь такую конструкцию.

Но, как выяснилось, Sentry отлично логгирует и unhandled exception! То есть, я сделал "не обтрайкеченную" ошибку, когда `insert` просто "стукается лбом" о constraint в базе - и эта ошибка, когда приложение упало, прекрасно записалась в Sentry!

И вот тперья сижу и думаю: **я не понимаю, как они это делают?** Что происходит? Они ведь не создают никакого глобального `try-catch`, который мог бы перехватывать все "бесхозные" ошибки. А как еще можно перехватить и обработать все исключения в коде?

Спасибо заранее за Ваши подсказки.

в самом конце: как у меня выглядит на их сайте эта ошибка:

[image: ошибка на сайте Sentry]

Comment: Может после краша приложуха отправляет ОС какой-то код (условно 0х0001234)? А дальше какими-нибудь манипуляциями достают эксепшен по этому коду

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a

Comment: Мысль интересная, но тогда установка Sentry затрагивала бы какие то системные штуки, например, меняла бы что то в GAC. А так - я посмотрел, это библиотека чистой воды, и при сборке проекта просто доьавляется несколько DLL. Которые просто копируются на целевой машине в папку самого приложения.

Comment: А, я понял, сходил по ссылке.. то есть смысл в том, что при Init'е происходит - таки установка глобального трай-кетча! ТО есть, она просто не происходит "у меян на глаззах", поэтому выглядит... немножко чудом :-)

Comment: А что если нет? Я ведь могу быть и неправ, но я хендлю анхендлед эксепшен в WPF именно таким образом как по ссылке, вполне возможно либа имеет своей способ

Comment: Вообще, Вы мне подсказали абсолютно логичный и полностью решающий проблему способ... который, поему то, не пришел мне в голову, хотя в явном виде я так в своих программах делал (именно для целей логгинга). Может быть, оформите как ответ? Там букально скопировать пару строчек "по ссылке" и дописать пару фраз. И будет ответ - вполне на уровне!

Comment: Я не думаю, что это подходит для ответа, скорее догадка